# Does homotopy equivalence to a subspace imply (weak) deformation retract?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173410/does-the-homotopy-equivalence-of-a-space-with-its-subspace-imply-deformation-ret) is a nearly same question, but with a slight difference in interpretation. We use the definition of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#Deformation_retract_and_strong_deformation_retract), which is different from that of Hatcher or Munkres (where deformation retract refers to **strong** deformation retract on wikipedia).

My question is :

> Suppose $X$ is a path-connected topological space, and $A$ is its subspace. If $X$ and $A$ are homotopic equivalent, is it true that $A$ is a (weak) deformation retract of $X$?

Both Hatcher and Munkres have provided counterexamples for the case of strong deformation retract, but not the one above. Please help.

Comment: Think of $X=$ the countably infinity wedge sum of circles and the subspace $A$ consisting of every circle except one. These spaces are even homeomorphic but $A$ is not a weak deformarion retract of $X$ since the inclusion does not induce a surjection of homotopy groups.

Comment: @NoelLundström Even the homomorphism between fundamental groups induced by the inclusion is not surjective, right?(just to make sure)

Comment: @NoelLundström Why not an official answer?

Comment: @Juggler yes, this can be shown by Van Kampen

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm on my phone right now and don't really wanna write out the entire proof in detail

Comment: @NoelLundström Do you mind if I answer the question in form of a community wiki?

Comment: Sure! @PaulFrost

Comment: magic conversation <3, I love this spirit in this website :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Noel Lundström has sketched a counterexample in a comment. Let $X = \bigvee_{i=1}^\infty S^1_i$ be the countably infinite wedge of copies of the circle $S^1$. This is a $CW$-complex with one $0$-cell and countably infinitely many $1$-cells. The space $A = \bigvee_{i=2}^\infty S^1_i$ is a subcomplex of $X$ which is homeomorphic to $X$; it is also a retract of $X$. However, the inclusion $i : A \to X$ is not a homotopy equivalence, thus $A$ is not a (weak) deformation retract of $X$.

To prove this, assume $i$ has a homotopy inverse $f : X \to A$. Then $i \circ f \simeq id_X$. Let $i_1$ be the inclusion of $S^1_1$ into $X$ and $r_1 : X \to S^1_1$ be the retraction which maps $A$ to the wedge point. We get $r_1 \circ f \circ i_1 \simeq r_1 \circ id_X \circ i_1 = id$. But $r_1 \circ f \circ i_1$ is constant, thus the identity on $S^1_1$ must be inessential. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an easy example. The subspace doesn't even need to be a retract: Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open disk centered at the origin with radius 1 and $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ its closure. Let X = $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ our topological space. There cannot exist a continuous function $$ f: \overline{\mathbb{D}} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$$
since $\mathbb{D}$ is dense in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, hence $\mathbb{D}$ is not a retract.
However, both spaces are contractible thus homotopy equivalent.